# Differential equation not working out

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ x'= \frac{-x}{t}$$

So I'm trying to solve the above equation in the following method. We can write $x'= \frac{dx}{dt}$. this makes
$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{-x}{t} $$
$$ \frac{1}{x}dx = \frac{-1}{t}dt$$
using integration
$$ \int{\frac{1}{x} dx} = \int{\frac{-1}{t}} dt $$
$$ln|x| = -ln|t| + C$$
$$x = -e^{t}+C$$

But this is nowhere near the real solution $x(t) = \frac{C}{t} $

So my question is where did I go wrong or is something wrong about my method?

Comment: How did you get from $\ln x=-\ln t+c$ to the next line? You should refresh your knowledge of logarithms and their properties

Comment: You appear to be under the impression that the map $u\mapsto e^u$ is additive.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the functional equation states $\mathrm e^{a + b} = \mathrm e^a \color{red} \cdot \mathrm e^b$ for real $a,b$, so from your result

$$\ln \vert x \vert = - \ln \vert t \vert + C$$

it follows

$$\vert x \vert = \mathrm e^{- \ln \vert t \vert + C } = \mathrm{e}^{- \ln \vert t\vert } \cdot \mathrm{e}^C.$$

Defining $\pm \mathrm e^C$ as $k$ and using $\mathrm e^{- \ln \vert t \vert} = \mathrm{e}^{\ln \vert t \vert^{-1}} = \frac{1}{t}$, it follows as desired

$$x = \frac{k}{t}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing $\color{red}c$ , write $\color{red}{\ln c}$.

So, $$\ln|x| = -\ln(|t|) +\ln(c) = \ln\bigg(\frac{c}{|t|}\bigg)$$

$$x = \frac{k}{t}$$

where $k$ is another arbitrary constant.